# camel ejb3.1 [org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException - No bean could be found in the registry for: AdvisingServiceEJB] -

Tags: ejb, apache-camel, jboss6.x

Working on web application project with ejb and camel. Camel is able to locate the ejb for pricingservice and not for advisingservice. Getting error while locating ejb bean. application is WAR package.

Any help appreciated!

my stateless ejb:

```
@Stateless(name = "AdvisingServiceEJB")
@LocalBean
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)
public class AdvisingServiceBean implements AdvisingServiceLocal {

/**
 * Default constructor.
 */
public AdvisingServiceBean() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void process(Object obj) {
    System.out
            .println("Got from Advising EJB **********************************");

}

}
```

interface:

```
@Local
public interface AdvisingServiceLocal {

    public void process(Object obj);

}
```

ejb-jar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>AdvisingService</display-name>

 </ejb-jar>
```

routebuilder:

```
public class PaymentsRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from(
            "mqjms:queue:queue:///testQueue?jmsMessageType=Text&exchangePattern=InOut")
            .log("Message received")
            // .to("ejb:PricingServiceEJB?method=processPricingRequest")
            .to("ejb:AdvisingServiceEJB?method=process")
            .log("Message processed");

}

}
```

Route works perfectly with other ejb which is commented in the route.

camel context listener:

```
public class PaymentsContextListener extends
    CamelServletContextListener<SimpleRegistry> {

private SimpleRegistry map;

@Resource(lookup = "java:jboss/TransactionManager")
TransactionManager txManager;

JtaTransactionManager manager;

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.contextInitialized(sce);

    System.out.println("Context initialised");
}

@Override
protected SimpleRegistry createRegistry() throws Exception {
    map = new SimpleRegistry();
    map.put("mqjms", createMQComponent());
    map.put("ejb", createEjbComponent());
    return map;
}

/**
 * Gets the {@link Map} that contains the data for the
 * {@link SimpleRegistry}
 */
public Map<String, Object> getMap() {
    return map;
}

private Component createMQComponent() {

    MQXAConnectionFactory factory = new MQXAConnectionFactory();
    try {
        factory.setChannel("channel");
        factory.setQueueManager("queuemanager");
        factory.setTransportType(1);
        factory.setHostName("hostname");
        factory.setPort(12345);
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assert factory != null;

    JmsConfiguration config = new JmsConfiguration(factory);
    config.setCacheLevel(0);
    config.setTransacted(true);

    config.setTransactionManager(getManager());
    config.setDeliveryPersistent(true);
    config.setConnectionFactory(factory);

    return JmsComponent.jmsComponent(config);

}

private EjbComponent createEjbComponent() {
    EjbComponent ejb = new EjbComponent();

    Context initCtx = null;
    try {
        initCtx = new InitialContext();
        initCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ejb.setContext(initCtx);
    // initCtx.lookup("AdvicingServiceEJB")

    return ejb;
}

private JtaTransactionManager getManager() {
    manager = new JtaTransactionManager(txManager);
    return manager;
}

}
```

error:

```
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException - No bean could be found in the registry for: AdvisingServiceEJB]: org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: AdvisingServiceEJB
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.RegistryBean.getBean(RegistryBean.java:85) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:78) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:68) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProducer.process(BeanProducer.java:38) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:129) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:448) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:118) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:109) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87) [camel-core-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:103) [camel-jms-2.15.2.jar:2.15.2]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:699) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:637) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:605) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:308) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:226) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1144) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1136) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1033) [spring-jms-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>PaymentService</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>name</param-name>
    <param-value>PaymentsCamel</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>routeBuilder-PaymentsRoute</param-name>
    <param-value>camel.router.PaymentsRouteBuilder</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>camel.router.PaymentsContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: It works now. but this is ugly solution. not sure this is right.

Comment: EjbComponent ejb = new EjbComponent();

  Context initCtx = null;
  try {
  // initCtx = new InitialContext();
   initCtx = (Context) new InitialContext().lookup("java:app/payments-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/");
  } catch (NamingException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  initCtx.bind("AdvisingServiceEJB",  initCtx.lookup("AdvisingServiceEJB!payments.advising.stateless.AdvisingServiceBean"));

  ejb.setContext(initCtx);

Comment: Can someone give me clean solution how to do this binding?